There are two more RenderTextures running when UseHDR is enabled in GraphicsSettings in unity
After enabling the UseHDR in Graphics Settings in Unity, I exported the Android package of the game, ran the game, and used MemoryProfiler to detect the runtime memory of the game. I noticed that there are two more ColorFormats in REnder Texture that have the same screen resolution as the Android device I am using, both of which are of type R16G16B16A16_SFloat. One of the depthStencilFormats is None and the other is a RenderTexture of type D24_UNorm_S8_Ulnt.
How do these two RenderTextures come about? And are these two RenderTextures really necessary?
